# How to crop a multipolygon shapefile?

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to crop a multipolygon shapefile. Most of the tutorials and other stack overflow responses have shown just polygons. I'm tired of following tutorial after tutorial and getting nowhere with my shapefile. Here is my current code. I'm reading in the urban/rural 2020 census database.

```
practice <- st_read(
  "tl_rd22_us_uac20.shp")

st_geometry_type(practice)
st_crs(practice)

library(ggplot2)

# Set the new latitude and longitude limits
latitude_limits <- c(40, 45)
longitude_limits <- c(72, 80)

practice_cropped <- st_crop(practice, c(xmin= 40, ymin = 72, xmax = 45, ymax = 80))



ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = practice, size = 1.5, color = "black", fill = "cyan1") + 
  coord_sf()
```

Here is where the shapefile is located: https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/UAC20/

When I plot the shapefile, this is what I get:
[image]

The cropping code is what doesn't want to work for me. I get this error: Warning message:
attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries

Please help this poor graduate student.

Comment: You may want to double-check your coordinates and where in the world that bbox ends up, e.g. `st_bbox(c(xmin= 40, ymin = 72, xmax = 45, ymax = 80), crs = "WGS84") |> st_as_sfc() |> st_sf() |> mapview::mapview()` .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv7jA.png

Comment: @margusl good point. I mixed Lat and Long up. I switched it but the code still gave me that same error.

Comment: That is just a warning (not an error!). You should be able to plug `practice_cropped` into the `geom_sf()` call after running `st_crop()`.

Comment: You are plotting `practice` instead of `practice_cropped`,  so it is no not possible to tell if it is not cropped. But as @Till said, it is not an error, just a warning. Try plotting the cropped data and see what you get

Comment: In your `st_crop()` call, you wrap the xmin, xmax, ... values in a `c()`. That's not the right way to do it. See my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

practice <- st_read("tl_rd22_us_uac20.shp")
```

Turn off spherical geometry, to make operations faster and avoid possible errors when cropping.

```r
sf_use_s2(FALSE)
#> Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
```

Crop: Adjust values to your liking.

```r
practice_cropped <-
  st_crop(
    practice,
    xmin = -130,
    ymin = 0,
    xmax = -50,
    ymax = 180
  )
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they
#> are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout
#> all geometries

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(
    data = practice_cropped,
    size = 1.5,
    color = "black",
    fill = "cyan1"
  ) +
  coord_sf()
```

[image]